# Docker Desktop for Windows, having trouble w/ -v bind mount

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, mount

To preface, I am extremely new to Linux and, by extension, Docker Desktop for Windows... so please excuse my ignorance.

I am attempting to run a program that utilizes Docker images, but I am having considerable difficulty mounting (using -v). Kindly see below for the abridged Linux line item I am entering, with exact syntax copied over.

**> docker run -v "/D/R tools/input_files":/src/data -v "/D/R tools/output":/src/outdir   --refsample file_seq1.txt --mixture file_mix1.txt**

Per the image --help, here is the required syntax:

**> docker run -v {dir_path}:/src/data -v {dir_path}:/src/outdir image [Options]** where {dir_path} are required to be absolute paths.

I have verified that my image exists and is usable. I have verified that the attached files (file_seq1.txt and file_mix1.txt) are present in "/D/R tools/input_files". I have verified that the selected image options exist.

Running my populated Linux command returns the below error:

**terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
what():  ERROR - utility::checkValidMount(): file_mix1.txt not found in /src/data/. Please check the parent directory's bind mount.**

NOTE: I have tried removing "" from {dir_path}; I have tried changing the location of my input files; I have reset Docker Desktop and my host machine; I have switched the / in the {dir_path} to ; I have tried adding "" to /src/data. All to no avail.

Other items of possible interest/help:

- I am using Ubuntu-20.04
- My directory is mike@DESKTOP-X1234A1:/mnt/c/Users/mike$

Thank you in advance, please let me know if additional information is needed. Again, I am new to machine languages and Linux (downloaded <24h ago...), so I am receptive to any and all suggestions.

Comment: If you're mounting from Windows then the path should be `"d:/R tools/input_files":/src/data` and if you're inside WSL terminal, your C and D drives should already be mounted under /mnt/ by WSL itself

https://rominirani.com/docker-on-windows-mounting-host-directories-d96f3f056a2c

Comment: @the.Legend Running the above line with d:/ returns "docker: Error response from daemon: invalid mode: /src/data." Running the above line with /d/ returns the same error shown in the OP. Running the above line without the leading D/d directory returns the same error shown in the OP. I am indeed inside a WSL terminal... having trouble understanding what my D drive being already mounted under /mnt/ means here (in terms of changes).