# How can Docker Desktop mount Windows Volumes?

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, docker-desktop

Let's say you're on Windows and you want to mount a volume like so:

```
docker run --name nginx -v "C:\\my\\path:/usr/share/nginx/html" -p "8080:80" nginx
```

This works perfectly with Docker Desktop, which uses WSL2.

However, with a custom Docker in WSL2, you'll get:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: invalid mode: /usr/share/nginx/html.
```

There are some questions covering this topic:

- [Docker on Windows without Docker Desktop volume mounting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71126797/docker-on-windows-without-docker-desktop-volume-mounting)
- [Docker Desktop for Windows, having trouble w/ -v bind mount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70911751/docker-desktop-for-windows-having-trouble-w-v-bind-mount)
- [How do you create a bind mount in Docker when running with the WSL2 backend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61803204/how-do-you-create-a-bind-mount-in-docker-when-running-with-the-wsl2-backend)

Their bottom line is: Use `/mnt/c/...`. But Docker Desktop doesn't need this. When you inspect a container created by Docker Desktop, you'll even see:

```
"Mounts": [
    {
        "Type": "bind",
        "Source": "C:\\my\\path",
        "Destination": "/usr/share/nginx/html",
        "Mode": "rw",
        "RW": true,
        "Propagation": "rprivate"
    }
],
```

How is it possible that Docker Desktop's WLS2 Docker daemon can handle Windows paths?